# Illegal offset after unsetting a key in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

I have an array `$data_list` which contains an element `date_time` with data in the following format:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["date_time"]=>
    string(19) "2014-11-14 09:30:03"
    ["follower_count"]=>
    string(4) "1567"
  }
```

In fact here is the full lot of data in `$data_list`: http://pastebin.com/wA7f9Aet

I want to split the `date_time` element into two, so it looks like this:

```
[0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(19) "2014-11-14"
        ["date"]=>
        string(5) "09:02"
        ["follower_count"]=>
        string(4) "1567"
      }
```

Note that the `date_time` element has been split, and the time portion has also been shortened down to `HH:MM`

I have the following loop to iterate through my array `$data_list` and have listed what each line *should* do.

```
foreach ($data_list as &$data) {
        $datetime = new DateTime($data['date_time']); // creates new var
        $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d'); // formats the date portion
        $time = $datetime->format('H:i'); // formats the time portion
        unset($data['date_time']); // Removes the old date_time element
        array_push($data_list,$time); // adds new time element
        array_push($data_list,$date); // adds new date element
    }
```

1. Iterates through `$data_list` calling each array element `$data`
2. Creates a new variable of `$datetime`
3. Formats just the date of this part
4. Formats just the time of this part
5. Removes the old `$date_time` element
6. Adds new `$time` element
7. Adds ne `$date` element

This works fine up until the array_push lines. I cannot work out why. I get the following errors:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'date_time' in /Applications/MAMP/path on line 70
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (0) at position 0 (0):

I can't work out why it's falling over at the `array_push` part. It seems to me like it's trying to call the now unset `date_time` element, but why?

Comment: are you trying to push on the parent array? or the current batch/sub array? anyways, you can't have two `date` indices, its supposed to be unique. and also make sure that `$data['date_time']` on all batch have proper date values

Comment: Spot on @Ghost - I am an idiot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the `$key` to detect the exact index of array so that you can push the `date` and `time` into the same `index`

```
foreach ($data_list as $key=>&$data) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($data['date_time']); // creates new var
    $date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d'); // formats the date portion
    $time = $datetime->format('H:i'); // formats the time portion
    unset($data['date_time']); // Removes the old date_time element
    array_push($data_list[$key],$time); // adds new time element
    array_push($data_list[$key],$date); // adds new date element
}
```

Comment: @JuanMendes thanks going to update and will keep in mind for next time.